# Creating a list of values from json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following code in python :

```
def myprint(d):
    date_list = ""


    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            myprint(v)
        else:
            if (k == "date"):
                date_list = date_list + " " + v


    print date_list

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://my-firebase-db-958b1.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = firebase.get('/Dublin-Ireland', None)
myprint(result)
```

I'm reading through a multi-level json and extracting the value for the key called "date". I'm trying to collect all the dates in the json and store them in a variable called date_list. When I execute the code above, the date_list variable only contains one date instance, it overwrites itself in every loop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recursing back into the myprint function, where your date_list variable is reassigned to an empty string. You need to supply that variable as an input param in the function, and you need to return the list instead of printing it.

Something like this...

```
def myprint(d, date_list=None):
    if not date_list:
        date_list = ''

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            date_list = myprint(v, date_list)
        else:
            if (k == "date"):
                date_list = date_list + " " + v


    return date_list
```

Why don't you want an actual list there? There are probably more elegant ways to handle that, but given the information outlined above, I believe that should at least get you a working version.

Comment: You're right, a list would probably be better, i'll look into that. However, the changes you made works for now. Thanks!